# Is sidescroller movement just offsetting the background?, MonoGame/XNA

Tags: xna, movement, monogame, side-scroller

When I make a sidescroller game and what to move my character do I just offset the background, or is there another better way?

Comment: there is a property called viewport, you are better off searching 2D camera class for XNA

Comment: http://www.david-gouveia.com/portfolio/2d-camera-with-parallax-scrolling-in-xna/

Answer (score 1):

A sidescroller involves you having 2 background images. When one's position crosses the screen it goes behind the other one and it keeps looping. This involves using the Rectangle struct. Here's a video I have for your problem exactly.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZEzD0GvImg